# Write a ByteArrayOutputStream as a file to data/data/packagename/files

Tags: android, android-workmanager, bytearrayoutputstream, android-internal-storage

I have compactFile: ByteArrayOutputStream() and I want to create a file in the directory

```
data/data/package.name/files
```

So what I do is inside a Workmanager

```
Application.instance.openFileOutput(localUriName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use {
            it.write(compactFile.toByteArray())
        }
```

The compactFile can be a an Image or a Video or a Document or whatever.
However, sometimes the file never gets saved in the path. And I want to understand why is this happening. Is there a size limitation issue? Is it because I don't do it right..? Any ideas?

Comment: If you open a door then you have to close it too.

Comment: plz....pieve of code! :)

Comment: it.close() ......